# Is there a way to tell git to stop tracking files before a certain commit?

Tags: git, commit

I have a git repo that has about 3 or 4 months worth of code. Is there a way to tell git to stop tracking files before a certain commit?

Comment: Your title says "before" but your body text says "after".  ;)

Comment: I have removed `github` tag because this is not specific to `github`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

In fact, the example given is perfect! (slightly modified)

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' <COMMIT>
```

Answer (score -1):

The following command will stop tracking but keep the file there intact.

```
git rm --cached filename
```

and then use a .gitignore file with the filename in it to stop future tracking of that file.